# jquery find function returning html nonexistent comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, comments

I have the next html lines:

```
<div class="large-6 small-12 columns">

   <div class="left">
      <label>Supplément</ label>
   </div>

   <p class="left itemSupp">0 €</ p>

</div>
```

I'm using jquery get function to get that '0 €' text. In order to do so, I have the next js code:

`$(document).find('.itemSupp').html();`

But that's not exactly what I get. In fact, when I use js console:

```
console.log($(document).find('.itemSupp').html());
```

It's shows:

```
0 €<!-- p-->
```

It's a bit weird because I can't find that comment line in the whole file. I've both tested Chrome and Firefox consoles and I get the same result.

I'm using Foundation framework, in case that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure exactly why, but it appears to be because your close tag is `</ p>` instead of `</p>`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a59Q4/)

Add the space back in and re run the demo, you should see what you have reported.  Without the space it should just print `0 €`.

**Edit:**

According to [w3 HTML syntax information](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html), any whitespace in a closing tag is expected after the tag (the `/` and the tag must be adjacent).

**Edit 2:**

As user3388636 put in his answer, you may want to consider using the `text()` function instead of `html()`; unless of course there is a reason you need the HTML versus just the text.

Answer (score 2):

Remove space `</p>`.

Use this:

```
$('.itemSupp').text();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm accepting user3507600 answer cause it's seems a bit more complete to me. But I'm also upvoting yours. Thanks again :-D